# Vertical Printing pattern in java

Tags: java

I want a program for printing numbers in below format in java.

```
for(int i=0,r=1;i<h.length/2;) {
    //System.out.println(h[i]);

    for(int j=i;j<r;j++) {
        System.out.print(h[j]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
    r=r+2;
}
```

The expected output should be

1

24

356

Comment: here we are not provide any code. Try some thing and then ask if you struck at some where.

Comment: That's nice - do you have a question?

Comment: if the input is 6, you should get 6 numbers from the user.                               The output should be in above format.

Comment: What did you do until now?

Comment: Mostly, if someone wants a program, he writes it. You should try that.

Comment: I don't see a) any apparent rationale between the input 3 and the sequence 1, 24, 356 b) how this relates to design-patterns c) how this relates to printing. Have you read the guide on posting questions? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please do, and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: for(int i=0,r=1;i<h.length/2;)
  {
   
   //System.out.println(h[i]);
   for(int j=i;j<r;j++)
   {
    System.out.print(h[j]);
    
   }
   
   
   
   System.out.println("");
   r=r+2;
  
  }

Comment: @Mathikumar, add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("1\n\n24\n\n356");
```

`</sarcasm>`

- more information is needed (what is your exact problem? what do you want to achieve? input -> outcome)
- what have you tried and where exactly are you stuck.

Edit your question and i edit my answer ;)

Comment: `if the input is 6, you should get 6 numbers from the user. The output should be in above format.`